# Pause Scheduled tasks in SCDF

Tags: spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

Hi I'm running batch jobs via SCDF in openshift environment. All the jobs have been scheduled through the scheduling option in SCDF. Is there way to pause or Hold those jobs from executing instead of destroying the schedules ? Since the number of jobs are more, everytime we have to recreated the schedules for all of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open issue: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#3276](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3276) to add support for it.

Feel free to update the issue with your use-case requirements and the acceptance criteria. Better yet, it'd be great if you can contribute adding support for it in a PR; we would love to collaborate and release it.